# Is EarthMoverDistance with signatures having 1 column supported?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

It is documented that if I want to use EMD with only weights stored as columns in the signatures I can do that given that I also give a user defined cost matrix. Well, my problem is that it doesn't really work, the function crashes if I try to do that. Are we sure that is is indeed supported? Here is pseudcode if someone is interested.

```
if (weightsonly) { 
signature1.create(h,1,CV_32FC1)
signature1.create(h,1,CV_32FC1)
//Fill in signature 1
//Fill in signature 2
emd = EMD(signature1, signature2, mp[metricSpace], cost_mat, 0, flow);
}
```

This crashes the function.

Answer (score 0):

this was a really stupid question to ask :)

It works, I was just passing a wrong metric, given that we want to use a cost matrix we need to specify the metric as CV_DIST_USER